# Print the name of day

Tags: c++, datetime

How can I improve this code? It takes a number in the range of [1,7] and prints its corresponding day.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::string;



int main()
{
    vector<string> name_day = { "Saturday" ,"Sunday" , "Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday" , "Thursday" , "Friday" };
    int n ;

    cout << "This program takes a number in the range of" << "\n" << "[1 , 7] and prints its corresponding day." << "\n" << "............................................................." << "\n";


    while (true) 
    {
        bool flag = true;

        cout << "Input a number : ";
        cin >> n;

        if (!cin) //If input is wrong.
        {
            // reset failbit
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        //If the condition is not satisfied .

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                if (n-1 == i)
                {
                    cout << name_day[i] << "\n" << "-----------------------" << "\n";;
                    flag = false;
                }

            }//end of for 
        }


        if (flag) { cout << "Bad Entery !." << "\n" << "-----------------------" << "\n"; }


    }//end of while 


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: this is not very OOP - when you ask for improvement do you mean: "how do i make it more OOP and amenable to change?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Isolate platform-specific code

If you must have `stdafx.h`, consider wrapping it so that the code is portable:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
```

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The code uses `std::numeric_limits` but doesn't `#include <limits>`.  A program may compile without the explicit `#include` because some other header might happen to include it, but that is not guaranteed by the standard.  To compile reliably, the documented `#include` files should be used.

### Don't use `system("pause")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `PAUSE` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example:

```
void pause() {
    getchar();
}
```

### Use `const` where practical

The `name_day` vector is not and should not be modified, so it should be declared `const`.  Better yet, it could be declared `static const`.

### Use better naming

The vector named `name_day` is well named because it is descriptive of the contents.  However, `flag` is not a good name because it doesn't suggest the meaning of the variable in the context of the program.

### Use string concatenation

The `main` routine includes this very long line:

```
std::cout << "This program takes a number in the range of" << "\n" << "[1 , 7] and prints its corresponding day." << "\n" << "............................................................." << "\n";
```

Each of those is a separate call to `operator<<` but they don't need to be.  Another way to write that would be like this:

```
std::cout << "This program takes a number in the range of\n" 
             "[1 , 7] and prints its corresponding day.\n"
             ".............................................................\n";
```

This reduces the entire menu to a single call to `operator<<` because consecutive strings in C++ (and in C, for that matter) are automatically concatenated into a single string by the compiler.  It is also more readable.

### Fix the spelling error

The error string currently says "Bad Entery !."  With corrected punctuation and spelling, that becomes "Bad entry!".  However, it would be even better if the error message suggested *what* was actually wrong and gave some suggestion to the user about what to do about it.

### Use indexing rather than a loop

The current code has this peculiar bit of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
    if (n-1 == i)
    {
        std::cout << name_day[i] << "\n" << "-----------------------" << "\n";;
        flag = false;
    }

}//end of for
```

Instead of a loop to look up the day, why not simply use an index?  Here's one way to do it:

```
while (true) {
    std::cout << "Input a number : ";
    std::cin >> n;
    if (std::cin && n >= 1 && n <= 7) {
        std::cout << name_day[n-1] << "\n----------------\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Bad entry: The number must be in the range 1-7 inclusive\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Note that this will flush the input stream on any error which differs from the behavior of the current code.

### Consider the user of the code

There is currently no graceful way to end the program.  It would be nicer if, for instance, a value of 0 or maybe -1 were used as a signal to end the program.

### Think carefully about using `using`

There is nothing inherently wrong with these lines:

```
using std::vector;
using std::string;
```

However, since each is only used once, I'd probably omit them and simply use the full namespace in the code:

```
static const std::vector<std::string> name_day{ 
    "Saturday" ,"Sunday" , "Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday" , "Thursday" , "Friday" };
```

### Consider using `constexpr`

Because it is a vector of strings, one can't make `name_day` a `constexpr` value, but it could be simply by making a minor change:

```
static constexpr const char* name_day[]{ 
    "Saturday" ,"Sunday" , "Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday" , "Thursday" , "Friday" };
```

This also means that the `#include <vector>` and `#include <string>` are no longer needed.

Comment: I disagree about using `constexpr`, `std::vector` is way more understandable and if declared const, result in the same optimization you could ask for

Comment: @snow_lemurian_snow: not quite the same.  A `constexpr` is evaluated entirely at compile time, while a `const std::vector<std::string>` still has a small but non-zero burden at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

This loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
    if (n-1 == i)
    {
        cout << name_day[i] << "\n" << "-----------------------" << "\n";;
        flag = false;
    }

}/
```

is superfluous.  All you need is to use `n-1` as the index:

```
if(n > 0 && n < 8)
{

    cout << name_day[n-1] << "\n" << "-----------------------" << "\n";

}
else
{
    cout << "Bad Entry !." << "\n" << "-----------------------" << "\n"; 
}
```

Also using [System("pause")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong), while convenient, is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: That should be `n-1`, not `n-i`.

Answer (score 3):

So, my comment is going to be a bit broader about practices

On top of what tinstaafl has said, please do not use `while(true)`.  Check for user input instead. 
I know it's not your focus, but `while(true)` can lead  to pretty bad design such as using breaks and gotos.

Also always have a return at the end of your main, enforcing type signature and having no warning will somettime save your day ;)

Finnaly, comments. Just an advice as you go on, write comments about why you do things, not about what exactly you do.
`// if the condition wasn't satisfied` or `// end of loop` are not very informative, code already gives you a lot of informations, you don't need to duplicate it

Hope it helped